# Locale-invariant string processing with strtod strtof atof printf?

Tags: c, locale, standard-library

Are there any plans for adding versions of C standard library string processing functions that are invariant under current locale?

Currently there are lots of fragile workarounds, for example, from jansson/strconv.c:

```
static void to_locale(strbuffer_t *strbuffer)
{
    const char *point;
    char *pos;

    point = localeconv()->decimal_point;
    if(*point == '.') {
        /* No conversion needed */
        return;
    }

    pos = strchr(strbuffer->value, '.');
    if(pos)
        *pos = *point;
}

static void from_locale(char *buffer)
{
    const char *point;
    char *pos;

    point = localeconv()->decimal_point;
    if(*point == '.') {
        /* No conversion needed */
        return;
    }

    pos = strchr(buffer, *point);
    if(pos)
        *pos = '.';
}
```

These functions preprocess its input so it can be used independent of the current locale, under the assumption

1. That the delimiter is one byte
2. No call to `setlocale` happens between these fix function and the call to any of the affected functions
3. The string can be modified before conversion

(1) implies that the preprocessing approach breaks on exotic locales (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system for examples).
(2) implies that the preprocessing approach cannot be threadsafe without a lock, and that lock must be added to the C library. (3) Just stupid.

If it were only possible to specify the locale for a single call to a string-processing function as a parameter, not affecting any other threads, none of these restrictions would apply.

Questions:

1. Are there any reports to WG14, or WG21 that address this defect?
2. If so, why hasn't these been merged into the standard? It would be nothing more than a new set of functions that take a locale as argument.
3. What is the canonical workaround?

Update:

After searching through the Internet, I found the *_l functions, available on FreeBSD, GNU/Linux and MacOSX. Similar functions exists on Windows also. These solve my problem, however these are not in POSIX, which is a superset of C (not really, POSIX relaxes on pointers). So questions 1, and 2 remains open.

Comment: Why don't you just run `printf`-and-friends in non-localized mode?  (That is, with `locale="C"`)

Comment: @BenVoigt. Thread-safety. If I set it without keeping a global lock, the other thread comes in between. Either it sets the locale to something else, or uses my locale, which it does not intend.

Comment: Then your question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/6561723/103167 ?

Comment: @BenVoigt Not really, I do prefer not to use locals at all. At least Question 1 and 2 are not answered.

Comment: I hope my edits have preserved your intention... before it seemed like you were proposing including the preprocessing functions in the Standard which I don't think is what you wanted at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt Good edit. Who likes that ugly hack.

Comment: Imbue a needed locale to a stringstream and convert away, what's the problem?

Comment: So many imperfect features in the C library: locales, multibyte character sets, wide characters, scanf, strtok, strncpy, ... They are OK to use for quick and dirty throw away utilities, but for precise industrial work, I'm afraid you need to re-implement them , tailored to your specific needs.

Comment: Not C, but C++17 added [std::from_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars) and [std::to_chars](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars), which are locale independant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BSD and macOS Sierra (and Mac OS X before it) support `_l` functions that allow you to specify the locale, rather than relying on the current locale.  For example:

> ```
> int
> fprintf_l(FILE * restrict stream, locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
>
> int
> printf_l(locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
>
> int
> snprintf_l(char * restrict str, size_t size, locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
>
> int
> sprintf_l(char * restrict str, locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```

and:

> ```
> int
> fscanf_l(FILE * restrict stream, locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
>
> int
> scanf_l(locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
>
> int
> sscanf_l(const char * restrict str, locale_t loc, const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```

As a general design, this seems sensible.  The type `locale_t` is not part of Standard C but is part of POSIX (and defined in `<locale.h>` there), and used in `<ctype.h>` amongst other places.  The BSD man pages say that the header to use is `<xlocale.h>` rather than `<locale.h>`; this would perhaps be fixed by the standard.  Unless there is a major flaw in the design of the BSD functions, these should be a very good basis for any standardization effort, whether that was under POSIX or Standard C.

One issue with the BSD design might be that the `locale_t` structure is passed by value, not by (constant restricted) pointer, which is a little surprising.  However, it is consistent with the POSIX functions such as:

> ```
> int   isalpha_l(int, locale_t);
> ```

A similar scheme might be devised for handling time zone settings, too.  There'd be more work in setting that up since there isn't already a time zone type (whereas the `locale_t` is part of POSIX already — and could probably be adopted without change into standard C).  But, combined with locale settings, it could make the time routines more easily usable in diverse environments from a single executable.

Comment: From `/usr/include/locale.h` (GNU/Linux): The concept of one static locale per category is not very well thought out.  Many applications will need to process its data using information from several different locales. (...) To support this another set of the functions using locale data exist which have an additional argument. Attention: all these functions are *not* standardized in any form. This is a proof-of-concept implementation. 

__Side note__: In this implementation `local_t` *is* a pointer (to a `__locale_struct`).

Comment: Interesting thought about the time zones.  Here is an existing C++ library for dealing with time zones:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html  This is currently gathering field experience.  Here is a graphic summary of the types involved: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz_types.jpeg (which does indeed include a `time_zone` type).

Answer (score 2):

sqlite has [locale independant printf](https://www.sqlite.org/printf.html) implementation which is good for your sort of thing as it makes doubles compatible with sql syntax rules. If you can include sqlite as a dependency then that might be a viable option.

Comment: another option is stb_sprintf from [stb libraries](https://github.com/nothings/stb)

Answer (score 0):

Glibc does not have locale-specific functions, but it has the POSIX-standard [`uselocale`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uselocale.3.html) function that allows setting the locale per thread. So instead of providing many locale-specific functions it is possible to use any standard function - including one wrapped in a library call - by changing the locale temporarily:

```
locale_t original = uselocale(loc);
// use printf/scanf/etc which now use `loc`
uselocale(original);
```